# Dynamically generate radio button and get selected radio button ID

Tags: html, kendo-ui, radio-button

Basically what i am trying to do is, I need to generate a set of Radio buttons with respect to the values in a Web Service call and i need to retrieve the selected value whenever a change in the radio button state happens. I have been successful to generate radio buttons with the values in the response of the API call. But i am not able to capture the change event in the radio button. I am trying with KendoUI framework.

Below is some part of the code that i tried out.

```
<div data-role="drawer" id="refineSearchResults" data-position="left" style="width: 50%; background-color: #f5f5f5;" data-swipe-to-open="false">
        <div id="refineHolderDiv" style="height:100%">
            <div style="height:40%">
                <ul data-role="listview" style="background-color:#FFFFFF">
                    <li style="line-height:inherit">
                        <span class="item-title" style="text-align:center">Refine Data</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="selctionsForRefinement" style="height:inherit;align-content:space-around">
                <ul style="height:auto;list-style-type:none">
                    <li style="margin-top:5%">
                    <label style="background-color:aliceblue">
                    DIVSION</label></li>
                    <li style="margin-top: 5%">
                        <ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset" data-type="group" id="listView1"></ul>
                    </li>
                    <li style="margin-top: 5%">
                    <label style="background-color:aliceblue">
                        BUSINESS UNIT
                    </label>
                    </li>
                    <li style="margin-top: 5%">
                        <ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset" data-type="group" id="listView2"></ul>
                    </li>
                    <li style="margin-top: 5%"><label style="background-color:aliceblue">AGENCY</label></li>
                    <li style="margin-top: 5%">
                        <ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset" data-type="group" id="listView3"></ul>
                    </li>
                    <li style="margin-top: 5%"><label style="background-color:aliceblue">DEPARTMENT</label></li>
                    <li style="margin-top: 5%">

                        <ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset" data-type="group" id="listView4"></ul>
                            <!-- <select id="multiselect2" multiple="multiple"></select> -->
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "http://some_web_link",
                        dataType: "json"
                    }
                }
            });
            $("#listView1").kendoListView({
                dataSource: dataSource,
                template: "<input type=radio name=abc1 onClick=categoryswitch>#:division#</input><br>"
            });
            $("#listView2").kendoListView({
                dataSource: dataSource,
                template: "<input type=radio name=abc2>#:division#</input><br>"
            });
            $("#listView3").kendoListView({
                dataSource: dataSource,
                template: "<input type=checkbox name=abc3 id=#:division# >#:division#</input><br>"
            });
            $("#listView4").kendoListView({
                dataSource: dataSource,
                template: "<input type=checkbox name=abc4 id=#:division#>#:division#</input><br>"
            });
           function categoryswitch(e) {
                alert('test');
            }
            kendo.init($("#listView3"));
        </script>
        </div>
```

This is the method that i have tried so far. Please let me know if there is any solution to the problem that i am having. Also if there is any other alternative to what i am trying out then please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please try following changes:**
*For kendo you can change your id to id='#= YourId HEre #' .*

```
template: "<input type=radio name=abc1 onClick=categoryswitch>#:division#</input><br>"
```

> To

```
template: "<input id='1' type='radio' name='abc1' onclick='categoryswitch(event)'>#:division#</input><br>"
```

and you can get you radio button id by.

```
function categoryswitch(e) 
{
    alert(e.target.id);
}
```

Comment: I will be generating more than one radio button based on the no of parameters on the web api call, so how does it help when we are hard coding the id of the element.

Comment: I did a slight modification based on your answer. I bind the division id that i got as the id of the radio button and passed it on the onClick event.

Thus the corresponding event was called.